# Wait for a response from the mysql server in a easy way

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming and wrote a basic login script *(or rather watched a tutorial)*, but my output in Unity is at first "User nicht gefunden" and about one second later "User gefunden".

My question: Can I somehow wait for a response from the mysql server in a easy way and still recognize a missing connection?

Unityscript:

```
public string inputusername;
public string inputpassword;

public string URL = "http://localhost/login.php";


void Start () {

}


void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
       StartCoroutine(LoginToDB(inputusername, inputpassword));
    }
}

IEnumerator LoginToDB(string username, string password)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("usernamePost", username);
    form.AddField("passwordPost", password);

    WWW www = new WWW(URL, form);
    yield return www;


    if(www.text == "wrong")
    {
        Debug.Log("User nicht gefunden");
    }
    if(www.text == "correct")
    {
        Debug.Log("User gefunden");
    }


}
```

Phpscript:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "********";
$dbName = "test";

$user_username = $_POST["usernamePost"];
$user_password = $_POST["passwordPost"];

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

if(!$conn){
    die("Verbindung Fehlgeschlagen!". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '".$user_username."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

         if($row['password'] == $user_password){
             echo "correct";
         } 

         else{

                echo "wrong";
         }

    }

}else {
    echo"not here";

}
```

Sorry in advance for the probably simple question.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Additionally you should not store passwords in plaintext in your database, use a hash function like `bcrypt` instead.

Comment: Also use prepared statements to help combat sql injections

Comment: Please do not mix terms up. SQL Server is a Microsoft product while you are using MySQL

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your advice. But at first it should only be a kind of test.

Comment: @Isaac Also thank you for the advice. Like I said at first it should only be a kind of test.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ok I have revised my post. Thank you too.

Comment: I read this but don't get it. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Programmer  First, I get as a return that the password would be wrong and only after about a second, the password is really recognized. So my first attempt was only if it is the right password to give a "answer" through the www.text. However, I do not know how to tell if the server is connected at all. So to make my question more precise: is there a function that does the `else echo "wrong"` until there is no return from the mysql server for a certain amount of time and then checks if the server is connected at all.

Comment: Didn't understand the question clearly but `mysql.connect_timeout` might be the setting in your php.ini you might be looking for.

Comment: @Viney So ´mysql.connect_timeout´ terminates the connection with the server after a certain time?

Comment: No, if your mysql server goes offline and didn't respond to the connection request then it will assume that mysql server isn't reachable, time which defines this store in this config

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

     if($row['password'] == $user_password){
         echo "correct";
     } 

     else{

            echo "wrong";
     }

}
```

1. You aren't checking that the passed in user matches the user in the database. Multiple users with the same password could log in add each other!
2. You are returning multiple responses, this is why you see "wrong password" initially
3. You aren't salting and hashing your passwords. This is inherently insecure.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a proper function? I have no experience with mysql so I do not know how to fix these problems.

Comment: @PCHD I don't regularly write php and sql. I can read what your code is doing, but I am not able to construct better working code.